# email exist in realty in asp.net and display this error

Tags: asp.net

```
System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required 
                        for an e-mail address.
at System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset, 
                                                String& displayName) at 
 System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset) at 
 System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.ParseValue(String addresses) at 
 System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(String addresses) 
 at MasterPage.btnJoin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
 d:\Visual Studio 2010\SocielNetwork\MasterPage.master.cs:line 25
```

Comment: What is the email address in question?

Comment: As the error suggesting the email address for which you are sending mail is not in the correct format. Debug you code and see what email it is using to send mail.